# iOS Gitlab authentication failed for Fastlane command sync_code_signing

Tags: ios, gitlab, fastlane, fastlane-match

I'm trying to setup fastlane for an iOS project which has one Git repo for the project and the project contains multiple targets for "different" apps based on the same source code.

I created a second git repo for the signing certificates which should be synced with match, but i don't know where to set the auth stuff for it, because my lane throws the error below.

I start the lane signing which contains sync_code_signing

```
% fastlane signing --env ENVIRONMENTNAME
```

and i get the following output

```
[⠙]  Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.12.2
[✔]  
[07:43:16]: Loading from './fastlane/.env.ENVIRONMENTNAME'
[07:43:16]: fastlane detected a Gemfile in the current directory
[07:43:16]: However, it seems like you didn't use `bundle exec`
[07:43:16]: To launch fastlane faster, please use
[07:43:16]: 
[07:43:16]: $ bundle exec fastlane signing
[07:43:16]: 
[07:43:16]: Get started using a Gemfile for fastlane https://docs.fastlane.tools/getting-started/ios/setup/#use-a-gemfile
[07:43:18]: ------------------------------
[07:43:18]: --- Step: default_platform ---
[07:43:18]: ------------------------------
[07:43:18]: Driving the lane 'signing' 
[07:43:18]: -------------------------------
[07:43:18]: --- Step: sync_code_signing ---
[07:43:18]: -------------------------------
[07:43:18]: Successfully loaded 'PROJECTDIR/fastlane/Matchfile' 

+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|            Detected Values from './fastlane/Matchfile'            |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| git_url      | https://gitlab.com/TEAMID/apple-certificates.git |
| storage_mode | git                                                |
+--------------+----------------------------------------------------+


+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
|                              Summary for match 2.198.1                              |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| type                           | development                                        |
| readonly                       | false                                              |
| generate_apple_certs           | true                                               |
| skip_provisioning_profiles     | false                                              |
| app_identifier                 | ["APPID"]                           |
| username                       | USERID                                |
| team_id                        | TEAMID                                         |
| team_name                      | TEAMNAME                                           |
| storage_mode                   | git                                                |
| git_url                        | https://gitlab.com/TEAMID/apple-certificates.git |
| git_branch                     | master                                             |
| shallow_clone                  | false                                              |
| clone_branch_directly          | false                                              |
| keychain_name                  | login.keychain                                     |
| force                          | false                                              |
| force_for_new_devices          | false                                              |
| include_all_certificates       | false                                              |
| force_for_new_certificates     | false                                              |
| skip_confirmation              | false                                              |
| skip_docs                      | false                                              |
| platform                       | ios                                                |
| derive_catalyst_app_identifier | false                                              |
| fail_on_name_taken             | false                                              |
| skip_certificate_matching      | false                                              |
| skip_set_partition_list        | false                                              |
| verbose                        | false                                              |
+--------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+

[07:43:18]: Cloning remote git repo...
[07:43:18]: If cloning the repo takes too long, you can use the `clone_branch_directly` option in match.
Cloning into '/var/folders/wf/_fzyy4y52hq4ssl02xmwwkx80000gn/T/d20211118-79026-m9y5x8'...
remote: The project you were looking for could not be found or you don't have permission to view it.
fatal: repository 'https://gitlab.com/TEAMID/apple-certificates.git/' not found
[07:43:19]: Exit status: 128
[07:43:19]: Error cloning certificates repo, please make sure you have read access to the repository you want to use
[07:43:19]: Run the following command manually to make sure you're properly authenticated:
[07:43:19]: $ git clone https://gitlab.com/TEAMID/apple-certificates.git /var/folders/wf/_fzyy4y52hq4ssl02xmwwkx80000gn/T/d20211118-79026-m9y5x8
+------------------+---------+
|        Lane Context        |
+------------------+---------+
| ENVIRONMENT      | ENVIRONMENTNAME   |
| DEFAULT_PLATFORM | ios     |
| PLATFORM_NAME    |         |
| LANE_NAME        | signing |
+------------------+---------+
[07:43:19]: Error cloning certificates git repo, please make sure you have access to the repository - see instructions above

+------+-------------------+-------------+
|            fastlane summary            |
+------+-------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action            | Time (in s) |
+------+-------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform  | 0           |
|    | sync_code_signing | 0           |
+------+-------------------+-------------+

[07:43:19]: fastlane finished with errors

[!] Error cloning certificates git repo, please make sure you have access to the repository - see instructions above
```

Do I have to install gitlab-runner locally for that?
I do not need to automate the process with gitlab-ci file right now, i'm fine calling the fastlane commands via console.

Comment: the problem was, that my ssh key did not work for authentication (I don't know why), so I had to add my username and password directly to the git url in the match file with https://username:password@GITLABURL.

Answer (score 0):

`Do I have to install gitlab-runner locally for that? I` - of course not.

You obviously don't have access to the git repository that the match uses.
Try cloning match repository directly, you may simply not be in VPN.